# PHP upgraded to 7.0 on Ubuntu/server, but hasn't updated on nginx/ajenti

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to upgrade my server/websites to php 7.0. I have successfully updated via terminal, i.e. 'php -v' shows the correct version.

However, it's clear that as nginx is installed on my server, I need to change a setting in the nginx configuration file as well.

I don't know much about nginx and didn't set it up originally, but I know that the configuration files are generated automatically via Ajenti V, so I don't think it's as straightforward as editing a configuration file directly.

Maybe, if I share a couple of screenshots it would help clarify the set. First Ajenti:

[image]

Then I have a config file for each domain on my server, and these are located here: /etc/nginx/conf.d/[server name].conf. Here is a screenshot of one of the files:

[image]

I can see that the php7.0-fpm.sock file is located here on my server: run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock, but I don't know if that's relevant.

Unfortunately the person who set up nginx isn't around anymore to fix this, hence the need for some assistance.

Comment: Hello friend, in your automated configuration file the version which use the php is not been displayed it should be something like 7.0.sock, check that the Ajenti have the correct php.

Comment: @LuigiLopez Thanks. Where is the setting in Ajenti? I can't find it!